# How can I save and again load the images to and from iPad's Gallery

Tags: ios, uigraphicscontext

How can I save the images to iPad's Gallery, and again read them from there into my App.
Is it possible to create a folder structure in iPad's gallery where I could store images generated through my app.

Actually I am able to save the images to gallery, I am using this

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

But don't know how to load it back into app from gallery. ?

Comment: use MPMediapickerController.

Comment: Do you want to load images automatically without user action or can you present a mediaPicker view controller ?

Comment: I think URL doesn't static in photoGallery. So answer is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ALAssetsLibrary`, then you can call `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:` to save the image and in the completion block you get the `assetURL`. This can later be used to get the image back from the library.

---

Docs are [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) .

To get the image for the asset url:

```
[self.assetsLibrary assetForURL:imageURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
    if (asset != nil) {
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]];
     }
} failureBlock:^(NSError * error) {
    NSLog (@"Error getting image asset: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: can u share a link to some sample code, if u have...because I have no idea about what ALAssetsLibrary is..

Comment: can u elaborate your answer little bit...I am able to save the image now, but dont know how to read it..

Comment: I think URL doesn't static in photoGallery. So answer is not possible.

Comment: @TheTiger, in some cases no asset could be returned, this would happen if the asset was deleted, user denied access, the asset is from photo stream and has been disconnected...

Comment: But URL would be change in case of adding the image into photo gallery too which is very basic.

Comment: The URL is the asset URL after it has been added to the photo library, that is why it is returned in the completion block called after the image has been saved. @TheTiger

Comment: Actually I just want to say that when user will save new pic in photo gallery the URL of image can be change it would be the same as it was before. is not it ? I think it is. So you can't specify the image from url from photo gallery ... It would create the problem.